# Using induction to prove that every integer can be written in a particular form

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> (a) Use induction to prove that every integer $n$ can be written in the form:
>
> $$n = \beta_0 3^0 + \beta_1 3^1 + \cdots + \beta_{r-1} 3^{r-1} + \beta_r 3^r$$
>
> where $r$ is a non-negative integer, and the coefficients $β_i$ have values in $\{-1; 0; 1\}$.
>
> (b) Show that this representation is unique.

It came to my attention the Basis Representation Theorem, but I am not really sure how I could apply it here.

Comment: Please use correct [LaTeX markup](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) for writing equations on Math.SE.

Comment: @Dan I have never used Latex before. I dont like to write like that, but I haven't found any example here to write it nicely.

Comment: The link I provided was pretty minimal. Sorry about that! If no one beats me to it, I'm sure I have a quick and dirty guide to basic LaTeX syntax around here somewhere that I can link you to...

Comment: @Dan I would really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Inductively show that you can achieve this for $|n|<3^q$ if you can do so for $q-1$. For uniqueness, subtract one representation from the other.

Comment: I am not familiar at all with Basis Representation.

Comment: I'm not looking at it at all from the point of view of bases, it's simply a statement about writing numbers as sums of other numbers. Work out what the induction step would mean.

Answer (score 0):

This result is possible because of the LUB property of the Real numbers; given any number n --in any base b--you  construct an increasing sequence of terms, which is bounded above--by n. Then this increasing sequence must (and does) converge to its LUB, which is the number n.

You can turn this into an algorithm:

$1$)Start with $b^0$ . Find the largest $b_0$ number in {$0,1,..,b-1$} that is smaller than n.

Output so far: $b_0=(b_0)_{10}$

$2$) Now continue with $b^1$. Find the largest number $b_1$ in {$0,1,2..,b-1$} so that

$b_0$+$(b_1)b^1< n$

Output so far: the base-b string $(b_1b_0)_b$

...

$k$)Working ( if necessary) with $b^k$. Find the largest number $b_k$ in {$0,1,2,..,b-1$} so that

$b_0+b_1b^1+...b_kb^k<n$

Output: the base-$b$ string:  $(b_kb_{k-1}....b_1b_0)_b$

This process gives rise to the increasing sequence {$a_n$} : $a_1:=(b_0)_b$,

$a_2:=(b_1b_0)_b=b_0+b_1b^1$

......

$a_k:=(b_kb_{k-1}...b_0)_b=b_kb^k+b_{k-1}b^{k-1}+...+b_1b^1+b_0$

The sequence $a_n$ is an increasing sequence of Real numbers with upper bound n, so that, by completeness of the Reals, it must converge to its $LUB =n$; a monotone sequence of Reals converges to its LUB ( if monotone increasing), andto its GLB if decreasing.

Comment: This is not about the real numbers; it is about the integers. What you need is the ability, given the representation of an integer $n$, to get the representation of $n+1$. To establish uniqueness, you have to show that if a number has two distinct representations, there is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, but if you consider an integer as a Real number, the LUB properties of the Reals apply to the sequence {$b_0, b_0b_1,...,b_0b_1..b_n$} of strings. And the uniqueness follows from the uniqueness of decimal representation for Real numbers

Comment: Sorry, but I am getting nowhere here. I need to use induction, so I have to show that it holds for n+1 too

Comment: O.K, I se, let me see how to do it with induction.